# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Tags: python, datetime

Python `datetime` does not allow subtracting `timedelta` from `time`; I suppose that's because `timedelta` can span over days and `time` is only within 24 hrs (hh:mm:ss.ns).

Now the question is if there is a data structure similar to `timedelta` that allows subtraction directly from `time`?

I understand that I can convert my `datetime.time` to `datetime.timedelta` to enable subtraction from another `datetime.timedelta`.
BUT I'm trying to avoid casting `time` to `timedelta` because I'm reading times from a large file and it's expensive to cast every time to timedelta.
However, it is a one time operation to simply replace `timedelta` with `some_datastructure` (if that sth exist) and subtract directly from `time`.

example:

```
t1 = datetime.time(hour=1, minute=1, second=1)
# t1 = datetime.timedelta(hours=t1.hour, minutes=t1.minute, seconds=t1.second)
t_diff = datetime.timedelta(hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=1)
print(t1-t_diff)
```

**p.s. how many *time*s did I use the word *time*?!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with all the times in the large file? Also, what format does each time come in in the file? (e.g. Feb 7, 9:30 PM)

Comment: The `datetime.time` entries are loaded from a pickle file. ex. `datetime.time(1, 5, 52, 582000)`.

Comment: As for what I'm doing with the entries, I'm expanding their span by adding/subtracting n seconds. Then use the outcome to lookup/compare values in an `OrderedDict` with `datetime.time` keys.

Comment: and what sizes are we talking about? I mean, number of elements, repetitions etc.?

Comment: in my smaller dataset, it's in the order of 10s of million entries.

Comment: ok then I'd definitely try to use something simpler than datetime.time - integer seconds since midnight could be one option, there's probably more.

Answer (score 1):

a conversion to `datetime.datetime` instead of `datetime.timedelta` would be more efficient:

```
from random import randrange
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

# some random times:
N = int(1e6)
ts = [time(randrange(23),randrange(59),randrange(59),randrange(999999)) for _ in range(N)]

# to timedelta could look like
td = [timedelta(0, 0, (t.hour*60*60*1e6+t.minute*60*1e6+t.second*1e6+t.microsecond)) for t in ts]

# %timeit [timedelta(0, 0, (t.hour*60*60*1e6+t.minute*60*1e6+t.second*1e6+t.microsecond)) for t in ts]
# 856 ms ± 903 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# to datetime could look like
today = datetime.now().date()
dt = [datetime.combine(today, t) for t in ts]

# %timeit [datetime.combine(today, t) for t in ts]
# 201 ms ± 1.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# now you'd do something with dt
ts_new = [(d + timedelta(seconds=5)).time() for d in dt]

# %timeit [(d + timedelta(seconds=5)).time() for d in dt]
# 586 ms ± 1.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But still - for the 1M element example, the timeits show that we're definitely falling into the critical `>1ms` range. If you want to go faster, I guess you'll have to use another time format in the first place, such as for example integer (micro)seconds since midnight.